# Using pureconfig to read tuples encoded as a list or array

Tags: scala, hocon, pureconfig

I'd like to use the PureConfig library to read a list of tuples.  That is, I'd like to read

```
{
  foo: [
    [1, 1.0, "Good job!"]
    [2, 2.0, "Excellent job!"]
    [3, 0.0, "Please play again."]
  ]
}
```

as a

```
case class Wrapper(foo:Vector[(Int, Double, String)])
```

A [PureConfig issue from 2018](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig/issues/426) is tantalizing:

> Think of tuples as containers instead; a pair holds two values with possibly different types and can be loaded as an array from a config, like [A, B]. You'll find plenty of use cases where you want to load such a structure but for some reason don't want to define a new object - for example, you can load a list of histogram counters (a List of (String, Int) entries) encoding it in the config as [[a, 1], [b, 3], [c, 2], ...].

but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually do it.

On the theory that I should walk before running, I've written the following to attempt to read just a single tuple, encoded as a list/array:

```
implicit val tReader: ConfigReader[(Int, Double, String)] = {
   ConfigReader[Int].zip(ConfigReader[Double]).zip(ConfigReader[String]).map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2, x._2))
}
case class Wrapper(foo: (Int, Double, String))
val mi: Result[Wrapper] =
   ConfigSource.fromConfig(ConfigFactory.parseString("""foo: [5, 1.0, "hello" ]""")).load[Wrapper]
```

It fails when it encounters the list notation: `[...]`

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pureconfig-magnolia` module does what you need. It's alternative of the `generic` module, but unlike it, that supports tuples. Once you added it in your build, all you need to do is add the corresponded import and create a reader for your wrapper class.

```scala
  import pureconfig.module.magnolia.auto.reader.exportReader

  case class Wrapper(foo: (Int, Double, String))

  implicit val wrapperReader: ConfigReader[Wrapper] =
    ConfigReader.exportedReader

  val mi: Result[Wrapper] =
    ConfigSource
      .fromConfig(ConfigFactory.parseString("""foo: [5, 1.0, "hello" ]"""))
      .load[Wrapper]
```

There you can find a README file and tests of this module: https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig/tree/master/modules/magnolia

Comment: Works like a charm!  It feels like the compilation speed is better, too, as noted in the magnolia module docs you referenced.  Thanks so much!